# How to add child/nested element inside json using json11 library?

Tags: c++, json, object, nested

I want to build following json object using json11

```
{
  "arrayOfData": [
    8,
    11,
    2016
  ],
  "objectOfData": [
    {"day": "8"},
    {"month": "11"},
    {"year": "2016"}]
}
```

I want to add array of data, nested/child object inside json11 object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[json11](https://github.com/dropbox/json11) supports the following syntax for nested objects and arrays:

```
{
   { //notice one more { here

     "arrayOfData", Json::array {  //notice {
         8,
         11,
         2016
       }
   }, //close

   {  //open
      "objectOfData", Json::array {
           Json::object { {"day", "8"} },    //notice {{ and }}
           Json::object { {"month", "11"} },
           Json::object { {"year", "2016"} }
       }
   } //close
}
```

Well that looks clumsy with embedded comments and the details of nested structures. Lets zoom out and look at the general syntax — the bigger picture — without comments and details of the nested structures:

```
auto object = Json::object {
   { key1, value1 },
   { key2, value2 },
   { key3, value3 },
   { key4, Json::array { ... } },
   { key5, Json::object { {...}, {...}, ... } },
   { key6, value6}
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

First we'll build an empty json11 object:

```
json11::Json::object parent = json11::Json::object{};
```

Then we'll build the child/nested array which we wanted to put on parent json:

```
std::vector<int> array;
array.push_back(8);
array.push_back(11);
array.push_back(2016);
```

Now we'll add above array to json11 object:

```
parent["arrayOfData"] = array;
```

Now we'll build the object using vector of json11 object:

```
std::vector<json11::Json::object> object;
object.resize(3);

object[0] = json11::Json::object{};
object[0]["day"] = "8";

object[1] = json11::Json::object{};
object[1]["month"] = "11";

object[2] = json11::Json::object{};
object[2]["year"] = "2016";
```

Add above object to json11 object:

```
parent["objectOfData"] = object;
```

Finally generate json formatted string:

```
json11::Json json = json11::Json{ parent };

std::string jsonString = json.dump();
```

Now `jsonString` should looks like following:

```
{"arrayOfData": [8, 11, 2016], "objectOfData": [{"day": "8"}, {"month": 
"11"}, {"year": "2016"}]}
```

Comment: too clumsy as it is too imperative. there has to be *one-line* initialization support for even complex json objects. that is possible in C++14.

Comment: what's worse is that it's not even right. you made objectOfData an array here (check the square braces). You should've created a map for it, not a vector.

Comment: @KristófSzalay Above code is working. Why do you think  `json11::Json::object` take only map not vectors?

Comment: check the json you've created. objectofdata is not one object with 3 elements as it should be, but an array of 3 single-element objects.